# How to populate Neo4j relationship Types values from database

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created Neo4j nodes in java.Now i am trying to create relationship Types but values of *RelationshipType* should come from Column **"Interface_Name"** in DB.
Is it possible to populate RelatioshipTypes in the Enum declaration itself?

```
public enum MyRelationshipTypes implements RelationshipType {
        KNOWS,FRNDS            //Values of Rel.Types coming from database column "Interface_Name"
        }
```

Is there any way to achieve the same?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the enum, you could use

```
DynamicRelationshipType.withName("value from db");
```

http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.1/org/neo4j/graphdb/DynamicRelationshipType.html